# Getting around System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access is denied

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, watin

I am using Waitin RC2, WatiN-2.0.20.1089, Windows XP OS with IE8 With VS2008 and NUnit-2.5.7.10213. I have added the sites to the trusted list, I have thread sleeps, I have tried "WaitForComplete". yet when the script goes "back"  I am still getting an unauthorized access exception.
Here is a chunk of my code, the exceptions are never caught inspite of the fact that most of the code is in try catch blocks.

public string FindAllLinks()

```
    {
        /*
         * This function is designed to find and use all of the links on a given page.
         * After clicking on a link it waits for 400 milliseconds on the page so the page
         * has some time to load and then the function "hits the back button" reseting 
         * to the originating page.
         * This function is not meant to be recursive.
         */

        string message = "";
        bool flag = true;

        //Get a list of all links from the browser instance
        foreach (Link link in browserInstance.Links)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(link);
            try
            {//clicking on the link to make sure it leads somewhere
                link.Click();  //If the click fails hopefull we will thrwo out of the try block and not execute the next two commands.
                //Console.WriteLine(link);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {//OOPs we have an error let's log a message.
                message = message + "The link titled " + link + " was not found, or did not work.\n";
                flag = false;
            }

            if (flag)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                //browserInstance.WaitForComplete;
                try { browserInstance.Back(); }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }//close if flag

        }//close for each

        //return the message
        return (message);

    }//Close function


    [STAThread]
    [Test]
    public void TestTitleHomePage()
    {
        bool testPassed = false;

        if (browserInstance.Title.Contains("<title>"))

        {

            string message = FindAllLinks();

            if (message == "") { testPassed = true; }

        }//close if

        else { message = "The Title was not the same."; }


        Assert.IsTrue(testPassed, message);


    }// end TestTitleHomePage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and I also get the exception. I think I understand what happens. When you first do `Browser.Links`, you get all the links of the current page, then you navigate to another page and return to the first page, but for WatiN it is a new page. So your enumeration cannot work because you enumerate though the links of the first page.

What I suggest you could do is to get all the Uri of the links, then try them one by one in a new browser

```
IEnumerable<Uri> uris = Browser.Links.Select(l => l.Uri);
foreach(Uri uri in Uris)
{
   try 
   {
      using(var browser = new IE(uri))
      {
          // do nothing or detect 404, 403, etc errors
      }

      // no error
   }
   catch(exception)
   {
      // log error
   }
}
```

Comment: THank you I thought that I may need to do each link in a new browser but couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: You are welcome. However I am concerned that the try {} catch() {} won't be enought to detect if the link is broken. For example, a 404 error doesn't trigger any exception in most of cases, so you need to check for it manually. It is the same of error 500, because the server will serve a page anyway. so you should test the page result. (see http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2008/04/catching-server-errors-with-watin.html). And if you liked my answer, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: + 1 if @KLA stayed in same browser, the links would have changed but and you'd have to get the new ones.  This new browser approach should get around that.

Comment: as an aside, I don't get the etiquette of accepting an answer but not +1-ing it as well.  Guess it is a newbie thing.